# grep listing filenames without content

Tags: search, grep

How can we list only filenames after searching using grep?

When I use

```
grep -i -R "search keyword" folder
```

it'll list all the inline lines of code also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
grep -i -R -l "search keyword" location
```

to get the list of files which contain the keyword.

Comment: `-i`: Ignore case; `-R`: Read all files in and under `location` directory; `-l`: for printing only the file names

Answer (score 4):

From grep `man` page:

> -L, --files-without-match
>          Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The
>   scanning will stop on the first match.
>
> -l, --files-with-matches
>          Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning
>   will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)

For you, `-l` option would be helpful.